# How can I find next sibling of 'a' tag which is inside into a table th tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am scraping companies data from Wikipedia infobox table where I need to scrape some values that are inside td - like Type, Traded as, Services etc.
my code is

```
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
table_container = html_soup.find('table', class_='infobox')
hq_name=table_container.find("th", text=['Headquarters']).find_next_sibling("td")
```

It gives the headquarter value and works perfectly

But when I am going to fetch 'Trade as' or any hyperlink th element the above code is not working, it returns none.

So how to get the next sibling of Trade as or Type?

Comment: You should update your question with a chunk of html elements in which your attempt can be applicable to reproduce the problem, otherwise whose gonna do such legwork for you.

Comment: Please provide the url you want to scrape. Also, it would be better if you provide your expected output.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM This is the URL, and the expected output will be Trade as- NYSE: IBM
                     DJIA Component
                     S&P 100 Component
                     S&P 500 Component

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM This is the URL, and the expected
>   output will be Trade as- NYSE: IBM DJIA Component S&P 100 Component
>   S&P 500 Component

---

Use the `a` tags to separate and select the required row from the table by `nth-of-type`. You can then join the first two items in the output list if required

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

items = [item.text.replace('\xa0',' ') for item in soup.select('.vcard tr:nth-of-type(4) a')]
print(items)
```

---

To have as shown (if indeed first and second are joined?):

```
final = items[2:]
final.insert(0, '-'.join([items[0] , items[1]]))
final
```

[image]